# Make checkbox larger (Website only supports chrome)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, google-chrome

- I am working on a web application
- Chrome is the only browser I am required to support
- I am trying to make a checkbox larger, as shown in the image below.
- Is this possible?   HTML/Jquery/CSS is the current languages used.

[image]

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

using css3:

```
.checkbox{
-webkit-transform: scale(1.1);
-moz-transform: scale(1.1);
transform: scale(1.1);
}
```

or for all boxes

```
input[type="checkbox"] {
    -webkit-transform: scale(1.1);
    -moz-transform: scale(1.1);
    transform: scale(1.1);
    }
```

only checkbox with a class scaleBox

```
input[type="checkbox"].scaleBox {
        -webkit-transform: scale(1.1);
        -moz-transform: scale(1.1);
        transform: scale(1.1);
        }
```

**IN YOUR CASE**
[image]
[image]

html:

```
<menu type=list>
    <li><label>Current</label><input type=checkbox></li>
    <li><label>My Goal</label><input type=checkbox class=scale></li>
</menu>
```

css:

```
input[type="checkbox"]{

}
input[type="checkbox"].scale {
    -webkit-transform: scale(4);
    -moz-transform: scale(4);
    transform: scale(4);
}

menu{
    width:400px;
    margin:40px 0 0 0 ;
}

menu li{
    float:left;
    width:50%;
    list-style:none;
}

menu label{
    margin: 0 40px 0 0;
    text-transform:uppercase;
    font-weight:bolder;
}
```

UPDATE Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/kougiland/Fp9Dc/

for cross-browser  [Styled checkboxes](http://www.456bereastreet.com/lab/form_controls/checkboxes/)  by Roger Johansson

Comment: Could you provide a fiddle please?

Comment: I am using the latest chrome and all four checkboxes are appearing identical.

Comment: yes i just made them bigger if you want some to be bigger than other then add a class .small .big .large and add some css

Comment: Still looking identical. All 4

Comment: so now a made the same picture and a new demo based on your question

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/45567/discussion-between-kougiland-and-eric-muller)

Answer (score 0):

Simply use this:

```
.youcheckbox{
     -webkit-transform: scale(1.1);
     -moz-transform: scale(1.1);
     transform: scale(1.1);
}
```

Comment: Could you provide a fiddle please?